# How to crop an image into pieces after detecting the edges using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a torn document reconstruction project. First I tried to detect the edges of the image which contain torn document pieces and then I tried to crop the image into the pieces through the detected edges using the sample code,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("test.png")
img = cv2.imread("d:/test.jpeg")

cv2.imshow('Original Image',img)

new_img = cv2.Canny(img, 0, 505)
cv2.imshow('new image', new_img)

blurred = cv2.blur(new_img, (3,3))
canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200)

## find the non-zero min-max coords of canny
pts = np.argwhere(canny>0)
y1,x1 = pts.min(axis=0)
y2,x2 = pts.max(axis=0)

## crop the region
cropped = new_img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
cv2.imwrite("cropped.png", cropped)

tagged = cv2.rectangle(new_img.copy(), (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow("tagged", tagged)
cv2.waitKey()
```

my input image was 
[image]

after running the above code i gets a output like
[image]

can someone help me to crop the torn document pieces and assign them into variables

Comment: Have a look at [contours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) and/or [Connected Components](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#connectedcomponents)

Comment: Have you heard the phrase ‘garbage in garbage out’? If you start with high-quality images which are well-light and with high-contrast between foreground/background the problem will get a whole lot easier and the results will also be a lot higher quality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The beginning of my workflow is similar to yours. First step: blur the image..

```
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0) # Blur
```

[image: blur]
Second step: get the canny image...

```
canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 30, 150) # Canny
```

[image: canny]
Third step: draw the contours on the canny image. This closes the torn pieces.

```
# Find contours
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(canny,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Draw contours on canny (this connects the contours
cv2.drawContours(canny, contours, -1, 255, 2)
canny = 255 - canny
```

[image: closed by drawing contours]
Fourth step: floodfill (the floodfilled areas are gray)

```
# Get mask for floodfill
h, w = thresh.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
# Floodfill from point (0, 0)
cv2.floodFill(thresh, mask, (0,0), 123);
```

[image: floodfill]

Fifth step: get rid of the really small and really large contours

```
# Create a blank image to draw on
res = np.zeros_like(src_img)
# Create a list for unconnected contours
unconnectedContours = []
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    # If the contour is not really small, or really big
    if area > 123 and area < 760000:
        cv2.drawContours(res, [contour], 0, (255,255,255), cv2.FILLED)
        unconnectedContours.append(contour)
```

[image: no small contours]

Finally, once you have segmented the pieces, they can be nested.

[image]

Comment: Hi what image should i define in variable res @Stephen

Comment: @KaveeshaChethiyawardena The 'res' image is a black image the same size as the source image. The only use of the 'res' image is to show the user the contours that are considered to be scraps of paper. I made an edit to the post to make that more clear.